# No value given for one or more required parameters. at using (OleDbDataReader rdrGLAcounts = cmdGLAcounts.ExecuteReader())

Tags: winforms, ms-access, c#-3.0

```
string sql = @"SELECT tblglaccounts.glaccountid as id,tblglaccounts.account as glaccount,
            rtrim(tblglaccounts.accountname) as glaccountname, credit.tblgltransactions FROM
            tblglaccounts INNER JOIN tblgltransactions ON tblglaccounts.glaccountid = tblgltransactions.gltransactionid 
            where glaccountstatus = 'True'"+" order by tblglaccounts.account";
```

Comment: If glaccountstatus is a yes/no field, don't put True within apostrophes.

Comment: I have solved this problem. thanks for the comment.